# How to create a Dropdown based on other choices in Python library Gradio

Tags: python, dropdown, gradio

I have a dataframe like

| HotelID | Location | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Paris | 15 |
| 2 | Madrid | 80 |

I would like to create a gradio interface with 2 buttons : `City` and `HotelID` and with output the price.

Here is the problem : I don't want user to choose an impossible combination (for example : Paris ; 1 is ok but Paris ; 2 is impossible). So I would like to filter the `HotelID` button knowing the choice of the city.

Details:

- HotelID is a primary Key

Thanks for your help

I tried to use the select method but in a wrong way I think.

I also ask chatGPT and its answer seems deprecated because the arguments of the functions doesn't exist. Here is its code:

```
import gradio as gr
options_1 = ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3']
options_2 = {
    'Option 1': ['Option 1.1', 'Option 1.2', 'Option 1.3'],
    'Option 2': ['Option 2.1', 'Option 2.2', 'Option 2.3'],
    'Option 3': ['Option 3.1', 'Option 3.2', 'Option 3.3'],
}
inputs = [
    gr.inputs.Dropdown(options=options_1),
    gr.inputs.Dropdown(options=options_2)
]
output = gr.outputs.Textbox()

def filter_options(option_1, option_2):
    return f"You selected '{option_1}' in the first dropdown and '{option_2}' in the second dropdown."

interface = gr.Interface(fn=filter_options, inputs=inputs, output=output, title="Dropdown Example")
interface.launch()
```

but I've an error in `gr.inputs.Dropdown` which has no attribute options and if I replace options by choices I have an other error

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me. I'm using gradio 4.4.0

```
import gradio as gr

options_1 = ['Paris', 'Berlin' ]
options_2 = {
    'Paris': ['Saint Denis', 'Eiffel Tower', 'Le Louvre'],
    'Berlin': ['Reichstag', 'Alexanderplatz', 'Kreuzberg'],
    }

with gr.Blocks() as demo:
    d1 = gr.Dropdown(choices=options_1, label="City dropdown")
    d2 = gr.Dropdown([])
    
    def update_second(first_val):
        d2 = gr.Dropdown(options_2[first_val])
        return d2 
    
    d1.input(update_second, d1, d2)

    outputs = gr.Textbox()

    def print_results(option_1, option_2):
        return f"You selected '{option_1}' in the first dropdown and '{option_2}' in the second dropdown."
        
    d2.input(print_results, [d1, d2], outputs) 

demo.launch()
```

Comment: I noticed that if I remove the Textbox from the code, the second Dropdown menu no longer works. But if you hide the Textbox using `visible=False` argument, the dropdown will work, so it's not mandatory to have a Textbox visible in your UI.

Comment: I needed to change what is returned by update_second to 'gr.Dropdown.update(options_2[first_val]).' Otherwise it's perfect and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue, please change the following:

- Change the word `"options"` to `"choices"`.
- Change the word `"output"` to `"outputs"`.

Once you have made these changes, the code should work correctly.